# UIFont render result is different from what we see on Sketch/Figma

Tags: ios, font-size

I'm working with a designer that is sharing assets coming from Figma and Sketch.

If I use the same exact font size available on Figma/Sketch for my `UILabel`, I see the rendered fonts are smaller than the same fonts rendered on Figma/Sketch.

I'm using something like this to initialise my font for the labels:

`self.font = UIFont(name: "MyFont-Bold", size: 14)`

Both Figma and Sketch work in `points` the same is true for `UIFont`...

Is there anything we can do to align our results?

Comment: Can you show a detailed example? Is the size off by 1/2 "pixel"? Or by 10 "pixels"?

Comment: @DonMag There is normally a difference of 2px/3px...

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Can you reproduce this with a freely available font, and share your screenshots from Figma and device?

Comment: I'm using Gotham font. @DonMag it should not be like this though...

Comment: Are you exporting 1x, 2x, 3x png files from Sketch? Can you share a simple example?

Comment: @MatterGoal - hmmm.... I grabbed a set of Gotham .otf files from a free-font site. This is what I get for a quick test on iPhone 8 simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/on6qe.png -- one is a `UILabel` added in Storyboard; one is a `UIImageView` with the exported png set from Sketch; one is a `UILabel` created via code with font set to `UIFont(name: "Gotham-Bold", size: 14.0)`

Comment: @MatterGoal - same as above, but this is from running on an actual device (iPhone 11 Pro): https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYTEL.png

Comment: @DonMag sound like I'm using a font different from what the UI team is using

Comment: @DonMag I'm getting font size from sketch-figma directly, rating what the designer has defined for the label... what do you mean with "are you exporting at 1x, 2x, 3x? "

Comment: @MatterGoal - your initial post said *"working with a designer that is sharing assets"* ... so I assume you mean the designer is exporting "assets" as images?

Comment: @DonMag yes... he is exporting assets as images but not the labels :P those are dynamic obviously

Comment: @MatterGoal - ok, certainly possible your designer is not using the exact same font(s). And really tough to figure out without seeing specific examples. Is your designer exporting images with lines / boxes where you are dynamically placing `UILabel`s? If so, can you edit your question and include examples that clearly demonstrate the size issues you're running into?

Comment: @MatterGoal - another thought... are you sure you're not ***scaling*** your images in your app? I'm assuming you are displaying the "assets from Figma/Sketch" in `UIImageView`s... do you have the image view's **Content Mode** set to `Top` or `Center`? Or is it set to `Scale` or `Aspect Fit`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this option works well.

```
UIFont(name: "Font-Name", size: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*(fontSize)/800)
```